# unable to run "update.php"

Tags: drupal-7

I had a Drupal website in drupal 6.x When i wanted to upgrade it to 7.x, the custom theme i was using was absolutely outdated, so i imported my Zen subtheme from another website. For doing that, i just copied the folders "zen" and "mytheme" from the other installation to this one. Then i selected "mytheme" as the current theme and changed some little things to adapt it.

The fact is now i'm experiencing the following problems:

1. I can't auto-update nothing. It downloads the files but then it stacks (and leaves the site in Maintenance Mode).
2. I can't run update.php. I can go on until i reach the "Run updates" step, which shows a blank screen. This is the main issue, i think, as it evidences -in my oppinion- a problem of communication between the site and the database.
3. In the Webform module i can't select "File" as a Field Type. This one is not that important, but it may be relevant for someone who knows more than me.

Edit:

Recently i migrated from a Shared to a VPS server. When i migrated, the subdomain in which i was experiencing the issue threw an incompatibility related to the lenght of the password of the database. I changed the password and it started to work again. This may help somebody for helping me. Thanks!

Comment: are you getting any php errors? Have you checked any of your error logs? Are you trying to update this on your local server?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. There are no error logs. I'm not getting php errors, just blank screen. And i'm working online, in a remote server.

Comment: Are you still having an issue? This was a month ago?

Comment: Yeah, i never resolved it. I'll edit the question with new data